# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL), expecting ',' or ')'

Tags: php, isset

I'm getting the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL), expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\AttributeEDesa\Upload.php on line 143
```

and this is line 143 code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['ops']=='info') && (isset($status_upload['Status'])) && (isset($status_upload['Status']=='success'))
```

Plz help me..I'm a newbie..

Comment: You cannot use `isset` on the result of an expression.

Comment: I think we need like 10 more answers saying `isset` is the problem.

Comment: @Rasclatt go ahead add your's

Comment: Im joining, `isset` causing the problem :D

Comment: Oh yes, use IDE with type hint support.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `isset` at wrong position.

corrected one:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['ops']) && $_SESSION['ops']=='info' && isset($status_upload['Status']) && $status_upload['Status']=='success')
```

Answer (score 2):

you are using == inside isset()

this is wrong,

if you need to check isset() and =='some value' do this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['ops']) && $_SESSION['ops']=='info')
```

Answer (score 0):

(**isset($status_upload['Status']**=='success'))

You haven't closed the call to `isset()`.

Answer (score 0):

These are wrong.

```
isset($_SESSION['ops']=='info')
isset($status_upload['Status']=='success')
```

You can only input variable in isset function

You should:

```
    isset($_SESSION['ops']) && $_SESSION['ops']=='info'
    isset($status_upload['Status']) && $status_upload['Status']=='success'
```

Answer (score 0):

change your Condition to

```
if((isset($_SESSION['ops']) && ($_SESSION['ops']=='info') && (isset($status_upload['Status'])) && ($status_upload['Status']=='success'))
```